# How can I do a join of SQL Server using the new join syntax?

Tags: sql-server

I have a SQL Select:

```
SELECT @AnswerGridCorrect = '00'+CASE WHEN Correct = 1 THEN '1' ELSE '0' END 
FROM dbo.Answer
WHERE QuestionId = 9
```

How can I get the data from the Answer table if I only know the QuestionUId?

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Question] (
    [QuestionId]       INT              IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [QuestionUId]      UNIQUEIDENTIFIER DEFAULT (newid()) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Answer] (
    [AnswerId]    INT              IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [QuestionId]  INT              NOT NULL
);
```

Comment: What new join syntax? ANSI 92? If so hardly "new"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[Question] q
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Answer] a
  ON q.QuestionId = a.QuestionId
WHERE q.QuestionUId = KnownQuestionUId
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT @AnswerGridCorrect = '00'+CASE WHEN Answer.Correct = 1 THEN '1' ELSE '0' END 
FROM dbo.Answer
JOIN dbo.Question
ON Question.QuestionId = Answer.QuestionId
WHERE Question.QuestionUId = @QuestionUId
```

Answer (score 1):

Not really sure what you mean but something like this?

```
select [your Columns Here]
from Question q
join Answer a on a.QuestionID = q.QuestionID
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT @AnswerGridCorrect = '00'+CASE WHEN a.Correct = 1 THEN '1' ELSE '0' END 
FROM dbo.Answer a
INNER JOIN dbo.Question q
    ON a.QuestionId = q.QuestionId
WHERE q.QuestionUId = @myuid
```

You just called 'inner join' and use the 'on' statement to select the fields to join